# What is the java equivalent of using structs to parse binary file headers /data structures in C?

Tags: java, struct

So, having used mostly C for file i/o, here is how my mind works when it comes to reading a file:

1. Create a struct (or structs) that reflect the headers of the file.
2. Read enough of the file to populate the header(s).
3. Validate and make decisions based off of the header contents, and read the rest of the file as appropriate.

What is the the standard way of doing binary file reads in java in terms of using information from headers? Please don't say walk the file stream one variable at a time.

Comment: *What is the java equivalent of using structs*, **using classes** (and objects).

Comment: No, I'm not asking people to equate structs to classes. I'm asking how people handle binary file input that involves headers, and I provided the struct background because that's my current file i/o paradigm.

Comment: 1. Create a class that reflects the headers of the file. 2. and 3. as in your question.

Comment: As you already exclude the correct way, how are we supposed to answer? What have you tried? You seem to have an idea already, so please state it.

Comment: Are you familiar with C? In C, we do a file read the size of the struct that pours over the struct in a single bulk action. Going back to the very last sentence of my question, do you populate this "header" class by reading one variable at a time from the filestream, or is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: I'm not excluding it, just hoping there was a better way. If that's the way it is then so be it. I just want to know if this is standard.

Comment: Use a [`MappedByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html), which is basically the Java version of [`mmap(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (which is how I would read a structured binary file in C). [Here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/bytebuffer.html) is an article on `ByteBuffer`(s) in general.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't think the ByteBuffer stuff will work--header parsing often requires that fields start on arbitrary offsets--for instance it might have integer values of 2 bits, 4 bits, 2 bits then 24 bits.  They can cross nearly any boundary.  I don't think ByteBuffer allows that without quite a bit of shifting, but I could have missed some methods in there.

Comment: Thank you! Is this the method you personally use, or just the closest equivalent to C?

Comment: @Krythic That's completely useless advice.

Comment: It's either ByteBuffers and painful manual deserialization (yes, even shifting) into custom objects or avoiding manual binary formats and instead using tools like protobuf to have ugly code autogenerated or relying on other formats that have existing libraries.

Comment: Does it specifically need to be Java, or can it be any JVM language?

Comment: @BillK It will work *almost* exactly like C (there is actually less boilerplate in Java).

Comment: Using a struct to read a file is poor practice in C. I don't know why you would want to replicate it in Java.

Comment: @BillK And you C code will crash and burn if your x86 CPU is trying to read big-endian data, such as common network packets like TCP. *"[The Intel x86 and x86-64 series of processors use the **little-endian** format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Current_architectures)"* vs *"[**big-endian** byte order is also referred to as network byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)"*

Comment: @Krythic This may come as a shock but Notch is no kind of authority or guru.

Comment: @IngoBürk Compare bank accounts and then we can talk.

Comment: @Krythic Being rich doesn't make you knowledgeable on every topic in the world. But let's end this discussion because it's just as off topic as your comment was.

Comment: *"Java is not the fastest language out there, but I doubt I would’ve finished Minecraft if I did it in a language I enjoyed less, so I’m happy with the choice."* - someone we should not name any further.

Comment: @Krythic I'm no fan of Java-but that wasn't my point. The point was that a simple "don't use Java" simply isn't useful, and is nothing more than noise.

Comment: @EJP You might want to inform the C community that they have beeen doing it wrong all these years then.

Answer (score 5):

> Please don't say walk the file stream one variable at a time.

Sorry, that's how you have to do it in Java, since Java doesn't have struct's.

E.g. to read a [TCP Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) using a `ByteBuffer`, as [suggested by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624426#comment62731860_37624426), this would be the way:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = /*code here*/) {
    // code here

    // Read TCP Header
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
    if (inputStream.read(buf.array(), 0, buf.capacity()) != buf.capacity())
        throw new EOFException();
    short sourcePort           = buf.getShort();
    short destinationPort      = buf.getShort();
    int   sequenceNumber       = buf.getInt();
    int   acknowledgmentNumber = buf.getInt();
    short flags                = buf.getShort();
    byte  dataOffset = (byte)((flags >> 12) & 0xF);
    flags &= 0xFFF;
    short windowSize           = buf.getShort();
    short checksum             = buf.getShort();
    short urgentPointer        = buf.getShort();
    byte[] options = new byte[(dataOffset - 5) * 4];
    if (inputStream.read(options, 0, options.length) != options.length)
        throw new EOFException();

    // code here
}
```

You can also extract the flags like this:

```
boolean ns  = (flags & 0x100) != 0;
boolean cwr = (flags & 0x080) != 0;
boolean ece = (flags & 0x040) != 0;
boolean urg = (flags & 0x020) != 0;
boolean ack = (flags & 0x010) != 0;
boolean psh = (flags & 0x008) != 0;
boolean rst = (flags & 0x004) != 0;
boolean syn = (flags & 0x002) != 0;
boolean fin = (flags & 0x001) != 0;
```

If you implement this in a `TcpHeader` class, you'd probably just keep the `flags` value as a field and do it in the getter methods, e.g.

```
public boolean isAck() {
    return (flags & 0x010) != 0;
}
```

And remember, Java doesn't have unsigned primitives, so all the values are *signed*.

Comment: I realize this is beside the point, but… Even a tiny read like that may not complete on the first try;  that doesn’t necessarily mean EOF has been reached.  It would be more appropriate to [convert the InputStream to a channel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newChannel-java.io.InputStream-) and use `while (buf.hasRemaining()) { channel.read(buf); }`.

Comment: How does this parse a 4 bit unsigned followed by a 24 bit unsigned?  Shifting and masking.  Kind of not what was asked for.

Comment: @VGR Yeah, you're right. Main point was how to use `ByteBuffer`, so I kept the `InputStream` logic a bit too simple. Don't know how making it a channel helps though, since [`read(ByteBuffer dst)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html#read-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) suffers the same problem.

Comment: @BillK Don't know where you get 4 + 24 bits, but that's only 28 bits, and data is read in full bytes, even in C. Although question didn't mention sub-byte header fields, I chose the TCP Header as an example to showcase how those can be handled too, as well as multi-byte big-endian fields. It does show how to get a 4 bit unsigned value, i.e. the `dataOffset` field, with the remaining 12 bits in the `flags` field, for a total of 16 bits, i.e 2 bytes.

Comment: @Andreas they are not when you are parsing packed headers.  They are scattered 2-3-4 bit integers along with flags and 16/20/24+bit fields--none of which are typically aligned on the boundaries you might like.  That is the whole point of the question.  Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream

Comment: @BillK *Nothing* in the question says that it's about *packed* headers. But even so, I show how to do stuff like that using bit-shifting and -masking, so what is your problem?

Comment: @Andreas Perhaps you are right--when he said headers and a struct I assumed that's what he meant.  Do you know what kind of headers he is talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry--Had a horrible time finding something appropriate!

Finally found a usable library: http://www.javolution.org/apidocs/index.html?javolution/io/Struct.html

I didn't realize it was that hard to find one--I just wrote my own when I needed it.

Here's an example from their docs:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
class Clock extends Struct { // Hardware clock mapped to memory.
 Unsigned16 seconds  = new Unsigned16(5); // unsigned short seconds:5
 Unsigned16 minutes  = new Unsigned16(5); // unsigned short minutes:5
 Unsigned16 hours    = new Unsigned16(4); // unsigned short hours:4
 Clock() {
     setByteBuffer(Clock.nativeBuffer(), 0);
 }
 private static native ByteBuffer nativeBuffer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be it is better to use specialized framework to parse binary data which provides some kind of structures, take a look at [JBBP](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser) and [example how to parse net packet](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser/blob/master/src/test/java/com/igormaznitsa/jbbp/it/NetPacketParsingTest.java)